# Why is my setTimeout() function not executing code after the 5 second timer I gave it?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

After I verify the password reset code via Firebase, I have placed a setTimeout() function to wait five seconds for the page to load. Without it, I get an error saying that it can't find 'userEmail' even though I have a function that waits for the page to load at the top of my script. I have placed several console logs and it stops at "started the wait", the line right before the setTimeout() function starts. The email `<h1>` that I have in place never updates as it's supposed to after the setTimeout function waits the 5 seconds to execute the code within it.

```
function handleResetPassword(code) {
    auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(code).then(function (email) {
        console.log("Code verified");
        var accountEmail = email;
        window.location.replace("/email/new-password.html");
        console.log("started the wait");
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("finished waiting");
            userEmail.innerText += accountEmail;
            console.log("set email");
            submitNewPasswordBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                console.log("submit btn clicked");
                e.preventDefault();
                var newPassword = newPaswordInput.value;
                var confNewPasword = confNewPaswordInput.value;
                if (newPassword != confNewPasword) {
                    alert("The new passwords must match!");
                    return;
                }
                auth.confirmPasswordReset(code, newPassword).then(function (resp) {
                    console.log("password updated");
                    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(accountEmail, newPassword).then(function () {
                        alert("Password reset successfully and you have been signed in.");
                    });
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.error("error confirming the password");
                    console.error(error);
                });
            });
        }, 5000);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("we have an error");
        console.error(error);
        window.location.replace('/email/errors/pswd-resetcode-invalid.html');
    });
}
```

I expected the email `<h1>` to be filled with the user's email and a when they click the submit button, there to be an alert saying the password was reset successfully but the page just doesn't do anything and the console outputs stop at "started the wait." I've waited about 30 seconds and still, there is no output.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this line.

`window.location.replace("/email/new-password.html");`

The setTimeout function starts a timer thread in the browser, but before that timer is initialised, the browser replaces the current resource with the one at the provided URL.

After using replace(), the current page will not be saved in session history, as well as it clears the timer thread, which doesn't trigger the code inside setTimeout.

Comment: So what should I do? I need to move the user to that page. Above the code I have a switch statement that decided which function needs to be called so before I call the handleResetPassword function, should I use that line of code?

EDIT: Just tried it and it didn't work. I'm a bit stumped on what to do with that line of code.